# How update excel file that is locked by another user

Tags: c#, excel

Does anyone know how to handle locked excel files with c#?
I'm trying to create an application that updates an excel file that is on the network which will be probably being used by someone when someone else will try to modify it.

So far I'm not able to write and save the file when is in use, and I'm pretty new to work with Excel and C#, so any help is welcome.

Comment: is the excel file setup as a shared file. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when a file is locked, you cannot open it.

Excel, however, allows you to prepare a workbook to be edited by multiple persons simultaneously. You have to prepare the workbook, and certain features will become unavailable when you do so, so this won't work for just any workbook.

Also, I don't know if you can also edit the workbook in C#, although I wouldn't know why not.

The steps needed are:

1. On the Review tab, in the Changes group, click Share Workbook.
2. On the Editing tab, select the Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging check box.
3. On the Advanced tab, select the options that you want to use for tracking and updating changes, and then click OK.

The full steps and an overview of general functionality and consequences of enabling this, can be found on Microsoft's website:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx